# Meteor observeChanges runs before screen reactivity

Tags: javascript, meteor

I'm using Collections.observe in my chat app. After submitted one message, all the users needs to be scrolled down to appear the new message.

I am trying:

```
Messages.find().observe({
  added: function() {
    $('.messages').scrollTop($('.messages')[0].scrollHeight); // scroll to bottom
  }
});
```

However, this function execute before the message appears in the screen.
But I need the observe function to execute AFTER the message appears on the screen, to scroll down. How can I do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe you should use `this.autorun()` in an `onRendered` event in template with `.messages` elem. I mean something like:

```
Template.myTemplate.onRendered(function () {
    this.autorun(function () {
        if (Messages.find().count() /*or some more specific reactive dep*/) {
            this.$('.messages').scrollTop(this.$('.messages')[0].scrollHeight);
        }
    }.bind(this))
})
```

Answer (score 0):

You could wrap it in a `Meteor.defer` or a `Tracker.afterflush`. But those are a slippery slope.

Ideally, `observe` should be reserved for 3rd party APIs (like maps, d3js, etc). By having an observe out there for something simple like a scroll, and then your template + helpers handling the same thing, your code is gonna be a hot mess in terms of MVC.

What I'd do instead, is put an index in your helper. When the `index === collection.cursor.count()`, you know you're at the most recent message, and then you can scroll to that template instance. (I'm assuming each message has it's own template here).